# Why is multiple assignment here giving unexpected results?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Code:

```
import numpy as np

def f(a):
    return np.array([0, 1])

N_x, N_y = 4, 3

U = V = np.zeros((N_x, N_y))

for n_y in range(N_y):
    for n_x in range(N_x):
        U[n_x, n_y], V[n_x, n_y] = f(0)

print(U, V)
```

This gives the unexpected output:

```
[[1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]] [[1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]]
```

But if I use

```
U = np.zeros((N_x, N_y))
V = np.zeros((N_x, N_y))
```

instead of `U = V = np.zeros((N_x, N_y))`, I get the following expected result.

```
[[0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]] [[1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]]
```

**Question:** What has gone awry here?

Comment: In the first case, you have only one array with two names, `U` and `V`. In the second case, you have two different arrays.

Comment: See my comment in the latest answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With multiple assignment you get only one object assigned to both U and V variables, so effectively you're then doing this:

```
for n_y in range(N_y):
    for n_x in range(N_x):
        U[n_x, n_y], U[n_x, n_y] = f(0)

print(U, U)
```

Comment: Then why does the following work? `A = B = np.array([1])` `A = np.array([0])`
This prints `[0] [1]` as expected.

Comment: Because then you assign a new object to the A variable (but  B still points to the first object).